# How do I display database records within the time range “Time.now” minus x hours?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I use a query with a condition and a time range from "Time.now" to -2 hours.

```
time_range = Time.now-2.hour..Time.now
Model.all(:conditions => { :created_at => (time_range) })
```

At the moment all database records, which have been created more than 2 hours ago, will not be displayed. All the records which are less than 2 hours "old", are displayed.

> E.g Some records created in current hour, As per my query It will show
>   me proper results,

But, If I come to next day and expecting the same result, I wont be able to see it.

So, My goal is to display records in time range...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
('created_at > ?', 2.hours.ago)
```

Comment: It will work if the record is created in between 2 hours from current time.
But My goal is something like this - 
If a user adds multiple connections to his profile
within one hour (2 or more connections) it becomes one
discrete story.
User1 is connected to 2 new users 2 houres ago.
Same activity done by user yesterday and I am seeing his timeline now then also it should show User1 is connected to 2 new users 16 houres ago.

Answer (score 0):

To do a time range, you need to split it into a start and end time in the query.  However, if one of your times is Time.now, and there are never any records that are created in the future, ie with created_at > Time.now, then you can skip the Time.now specification.

So, generally

```
@models = Model.all(:conditions => ["created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?", time_a, time_b])
```

when time_b is never going to be in the future, this can be simplified to

```
@models = Model.all(:conditions => ["created_at >= ? ", time_a])
```

Comment: It will work if the record is created in between 2 hours from current time.
But My goal is something like this - 
If a user adds multiple connections to his profile
within one hour (2 or more connections) it becomes one
discrete story.
User1 is connected to 2 new users 2 houres ago.
Same activity done by user yesterday and I am seeing his timeline now then also it should show User1 is connected to 2 new users 16 houres ago.

Comment: I've answered your original question - i think you need to put this in a new question, with some more details about what you want to do.